# Passing a path ("key1.key2") from a bash variable to jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am having trouble accessing bash variable inside 'jq'.
The snippet below shows my bash loop to check for missing keys in a Json file.

```
#!/bin/sh
for key in "key1" "key2.key3"; do
  echo "$key"
  if ! cat ${JSON_FILE} | jq --arg KEY "$key" -e '.[$KEY]'; then
    missingKeys+=${key}
  fi
done
```

JSON_FILE:

```
{
  "key1": "val1",
  "key2": {
    "key3": "val3"
  }
}
```

The script works correctly for top level keys such as "key1". But it does not work correctly (returns null) for "key2.key3".

'jq' on the command line does return the correct value

```
cat input.json | jq '.key2.key3'
"val3"
```

I followed answers from other posts to come to this solution. However can't seem to figure out why it does not work for nested json keys.

Comment: You're asking it to look up something in the structure `{ "key2.key3": "val3" }`. That's different from the structure you actually have, so it's no surprise that it doesn't work.

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're calling jq once per key, instead of having it process all your possible keys in one invocation? It would be much more efficient to be able to use `readarray -t missingKeys < <(jq ...)`; a comma-separated list of expressions will be evaluated after each other into separate outputs, making this fairly straightforward to implement.

Comment: Alternately, you could tell jq to list all the paths that your json file _does_ contain, and then use `comm` or such to find the items present in a (presorted) expected list, but not in that output list. Which is to say -- lots of alternatives that don't require running jq over and over.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--arg` prevents your data from being incorrectly parsed as syntax. Usually, a shell variable you're passing into `jq` contains literal data, so this is the correct thing.

In this case, your variable contains syntax, not literal data: The `.` isn't part of the string you want to do a lookup by, but is instead an instruction to jq to do two separate lookups one after the other.

So, in this case, you should do the more obvious thing, *instead of* using `--arg`:

```
jq -e ".$KEY"
```