# Can jq parse more than one level key from variable?

Tags: bash, variables, jq

I have a json file:

```
{
  "rec_9M":
    {
    "id":"000",
    "rec_E":
        [
          {
            "id":"111"
          } ,
          {
            "id":"222"
          }           
        ]
    }
}
```

I need to change values rec_9M.rec_E[].id but I need to use a universal bash function for that, which can be using for changing values on different levels (rec_9M.id or rec_9M.rec_E[].files[].id)

I tryed:

```
VAR=rec_9M.rec_E[]
NUM=555

echo $(cat config.json) | jq --arg VAR_I $VAR --arg NUM_I $NUM '.[$VAR_I].id = $NUM_I' > config_t.json
cat config_t.json
```

Expect:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsLMU.png)

```
{
  "rec_9M": {
    "id": "000",
    "rec_E": [
      {
        "id": "555"
      },
      {
        "id": "555"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Reality:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZq1W.png)

```
{
  "rec_9M": {
    "id": "000",
    "rec_E": [
      {
        "id": "111"
      },
      {
        "id": "222"
      }
    ]
  },
  "rec_9M.rec_E[]": {
    "id": "555"
  }
}
```

If key was hardcoded - everything works correctly.:

```
echo $(cat config.json) | jq --arg VAR_I $VAR --arg NUM_I $NUM '.rec_9M.rec_E[].id = $NUM_I' > config_t.json
```

Also I tryed any combinations of using VAR_I in jq with quotes and special symbols, for example "($VAR_I)". Results are the same or jq parsing errors.

Maybe anybody know a solution?

Comment: [edit] your question to only show text, no images or links.

Comment: Aside: `echo $(anything) | ...` is better replaced with `anything | ...`

Comment: More on-point -- you aren't giving us enough details to reproduce your problem. Are you putting a jq expression, instead of a literal key, in `$VAR`? If so, you need to _show_ that as part of the question itself; don't make people guess what you're trying to do that causes the bug.

Comment: If that **is** what you're trying to do, the question is arguably duplicative of [Passing a path from a bash variable to jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63082535/passing-a-path-key1-key2-from-a-bash-variable-to-jq) -- see how the OP of that question actually shows an example of the values they were passing in.

Comment: Remember, the _whole point_ of using `--arg key "$value"` is to _prevent_ literal values from being misunderstood as jq code. If you **want** something to be treated as jq code instead of as a literal value, you need to go out of your way to do so.

Comment: (To hammer it in: We need a [mre], code we can copy-and-paste with _no changes whatsoever_ to see the same problem and test our fixes. Needing to assign a value to `VAR` or to `NUM` _is a change_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way uses [`getpath()`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#getpath) to extract the paths of the input JSON based on a variable (Or other string):

```bash
$ jq --arg path "rec_9M.rec_E" --arg i 555 'getpath($path | split("."))[] += {id: $i}' config.json
{
  "rec_9M": {
    "id": "000",
    "rec_E": [
      {
        "id": "555"
      },
      {
        "id": "555"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note leaving the trailing `[]` off the path; this only works with paths through object elements that end in an array of objects.

Another, more flexible but also more fragile approach involves putting the path held in the shell variable directly in the `jq` program:

```bash
$ path_var=".rec_9M.rec_E[].id"
$ jq --arg i 555 "$path_var"' |= $i' config.json
{
  "rec_9M": {
    "id": "000",
    "rec_E": [
      {
        "id": "555"
      },
      {
        "id": "555"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Note having to put a leading `.` in the path expression.

---

`echo $(cat config.json)` has so many things wrong with it. `jq` takes the file names of JSON documents as arguments; use that. Or even a Useless Use of Cat like `cat config.json | jq ...` for example purposes is fine if you intend to replace the `cat` part with something more complex like a `curl` request or other command that outputs JSON... but don't combine it with `echo`. Besides introducing needless steps, if your shell's version of `echo` does things like replace `\n` with a literal newline, it's going to break everything else if escape sequences are present in strings in the JSON.